# io.swagger.codegen.v3 swagger-codegen-maven-plugin does not generate html documentation

Tags: java, maven, swagger, openapi

I want to generate html swagger documentation from yml file by the means of

```
        <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.35</version>
```

I have a next plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.35</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yml</sourceFolder>
                            </configOptions>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yml</inputSpec>
                            <language>html</language>
                            <environmentVariables>
                                <supportingFiles>false</supportingFiles>
                            </environmentVariables>
                            <output>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</output>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

After I run mvn clean install I expect documentation to be generated, but I got nothing.
Documentation is not generated at all. I've checked all possible folders - no result.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my configuration or provide working example ?

Thanks!

P.S. When I change html to java/spring code is generated and everything looks good. But html does not work.